# Force open the details / summary tag for Print in Chrome

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, printing

I try to print the content of the details tag in Chrome but I can't force it to open.

This is what I have in my print CSS :

```
details, details > * { display:block !important; }
```

But the content appear only if I open the details before printing the page.

Is there any way to force opening details by css print on chrome ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by forcing the opening details tag with BeforePrint and Afterprint

```
class App.Views.main extends backbone.View
el : "body"
events : 
    "click [data-auto-focus]":"autoFocus"
initialize : () ->
    # Add conditional classname based on support
    $('html').addClass( (if $.fn.details.support then 'details' else 'no-details'))
    $('details').details()

    if (window.matchMedia)
        mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print')
        mediaQueryList.addListener (mql) =>
            if (mql.matches)
                @beforePrint()
            else 
                @afterPrint()

    window.onbeforeprint = => @beforePrint
    window.onafterprint = => @afterPrint

render : () ->

openedDetailsBeforePrint : null

beforePrint : () ->
    console.log "before print"
    @openedDetailsBeforePrint = @$el.find('details[open], details.open')
    if ($('html').hasClass('no-details')) then @$el.find('details').addClass("open") else @$el.find('details').attr("open", "")

afterPrint : () ->
    console.log "after print"
    @$el.find('details').removeClass(".open").removeAttr("open")
    if ($('html').hasClass('no-details')) then @openedDetailsBeforePrint.addClass("open") else @openedDetailsBeforePrint.attr("open", "")


autoFocus : (e) ->
    $element = if (e.currentTarget) then $(e.currentTarget) else $(e.srcElement)
    return $($element.attr "data-auto-focus").focus()
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for supplying an example that works well with modern browsers and old browsers.

Answer (score 4):

Reasonable cross-browser solution with jQuery (not Opera)...adapted from https://www.tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/:

```js
    // Set up before/after handlers
    var beforePrint = function() {
        $("details").attr('open', '');
    };
    var afterPrint = function() {
        $("details").removeAttr('open');
    };
    
    // Webkit
    if (window.matchMedia) {
        var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
        mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
            if (mql.matches) {
                beforePrint();
            } else {
                afterPrint();
            }
        });
    }

    // IE, Firefox
    window.onbeforeprint = beforePrint;
    window.onafterprint = afterPrint;
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution in vanilla JavaScript which restores the state of opened/closed details tags after printing:

```js
    // open closed details elements for printing
    window.addEventListener('beforeprint',() =>
    {
        const allDetails = document.body.querySelectorAll('details');
        for(let i=0; i<allDetails.length; i++)
        {
            if(allDetails[i].open)
            {
                allDetails[i].dataset.open = '1';
            }
            else
            {
                allDetails[i].setAttribute('open', '');
            }
        }
    });

    // after printing close details elements not opened before
    window.addEventListener('afterprint',() =>
    {
        const allDetails = document.body.querySelectorAll('details');
        for(let i=0; i<allDetails.length; i++)
        {
            if(allDetails[i].dataset.open)
            {
                allDetails[i].dataset.open = '';
            }
            else
            {
                allDetails[i].removeAttribute('open');
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Great solution! But currently you add a data attribute if the details was already open. If you do it the opposite way (allDetails[i].dataset.closed=1), then you can restrict you afterprint query with 'details[data-closed]' creating a smaller loop and less DOM manipulations.

Comment: This was the only solution of all the ones presented on this page, that fully worked for a list of about 30 details elements, where some of the others didn't open them, and some of them caused only the first page to print (when there should have been 3 pages worth)

Answer (score 4):

Based on the answers from Christopher and Benjamin, I've created the following code:

```js
window.matchMedia("print").addEventListener("change", evt => {
    if (evt.matches) {
        elms = document.body.querySelectorAll("details:not([open])");
        for (e of elms) {
            e.setAttribute("open", "");
            e.dataset.wasclosed = "";
        }
    } else {
        elms = document.body.querySelectorAll("details[data-wasclosed]");
        for (e of elms) {
            e.removeAttribute("open");
            delete e.dataset.wasclosed;
        }
    }
})
```

Features:

- Restores state after the print command so that details that were already open, stay open.
- Minimize DOM manipulation by only altering details that are closed.
- Support DevTools print emulation by using the print media query instead of the print event handler.

Comment: Nice, very clean!

Answer (score 0):

For this specific case (which I see today, but it takes time on StackOverflow), I think the best solution to this is add in CSS the **details** tag to the list of **@media *print***, something like:

```
@media print {
    …
    details, details > * { display:block !important; }
}
```

**A simple method in jQuery: (updated)**

```
var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
mediaQueryList.addListener( printTest );

function printTest(mql) {
    dt = $( 'details' )
    if (mql.matches) {
        dt.each( function( index ){
            b = $(this).attr('open');
            if ( !b ){
                $(this).attr('open','');
                $(this).attr('print','');
            }
         });
    } else {
        dt.each( function( index ){
            b = $(this).attr('print');
            if ( !b ){
                $(this).removeAttr('open');
                $(this).removeAttr('print');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This **printTest** method verify if matches.
**matches:** open *closed* details elements and add an attribute *print* to close after.
**!matches:** close details elements with *print* attribute (and remove this attributes: open and print)

---

Looks more about this in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jam65st/9rj9vvt3/)

Comment: The original question don't uses the tag **@media print**, but rules need success on this, unfortunately, this doesn't possible yet, then you need use an event and a method to can do a print of collapsed details.

Comment: But **neil**, your proposed js code change the UI after print... ctrl+c + ctrl-v is easy, but look the logic of the question is another task; the question is based on CSS, in the near future HTML&CSS will have more about **details** and the logic of the answer will be **@media print**

Comment: Yes, no CSS option at present but an alternative scripted solution for now is better than nothing, no?

Comment: Yes, **neil** but your script change the state of all details in UI after print, test my abstraction and test in opera too.

Comment: Note that with using mediaQueryList (or matchMedia as the current implementation), you even support print emulation in Chrome's DevTools. Using the beforeprint event handler only works when really starting a print.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short answer in plain vanilla JavaScript. This just loops through all `details` tags, opens them all when printing, then closes them all after printing:

```js
// Open all details tags when printing.
window.addEventListener( 'beforeprint', () => {
    [].forEach.call( document.querySelectorAll( 'details' ), el => el.setAttribute( 'open', '' ) )
} )

// Close all details tags after printing.
window.addEventListener( 'afterprint', () => {
    [].forEach.call( document.querySelectorAll( 'details' ), el => el.removeAttribute( 'open' ) )
} )
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2024, here's what I went with that works for me in Chrome, Firefox, & Safari on macOS, and it takes into account already open/closed `details`:

```js
window.addEventListener('beforeprint', (event) => {
  for (const detailEl of document.querySelectorAll('details')) {
    if (detailEl.getAttribute('open') == null) {
      detailEl.setAttribute('data-was-closed', 'true')
    }
    detailEl.setAttribute('open', '')
  }
})

window.addEventListener('afterprint', (event) => {
  for (const detailEl of document.querySelectorAll('details')) {
    if (detailEl.getAttribute('data-was-closed') != null) {
      detailEl.removeAttribute('data-was-closed')
      detailEl.removeAttribute('open')
    }
  }
})
```

If you don't want to use a [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop, you can use [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) with or without [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), or you can use it with the [array spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```js
// If your browser supports `.forEach()` on a `NodeList`.
// Browser support: https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_nodelist_foreach
document.querySelectorAll('details').forEach(/* ... */)

// If you have `Array.from()` through a polyfill but not `.forEach()` on a `NodeList`.
// Browser support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#browser_compatibility
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('details')).forEach(/* ... */)

// If you don't have `Array.from()` but do have a transpilation method
// that can handle this `NodeList` to `Array` conversion.
// Browser support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#browser_compatibility
[...document.querySelectorAll('details')].forEach(/* ... */)
```