# Using HTML5 details element in printing

Tags: css, printing

We use the HTML5 element `<details>` to offer simple show/hide functionality.

This works fine on-screen but in print, any `<details>` elements not already open on screen are hidden when printing.

I thought this would work:

```
@media print {
    details { display:block !important }
}
```

but it doesn't.

Obviously, this represents a negative print user experience - has anybody managed to get this to work for printing?

Thanks

Comment: Note that `details` is not an HTML5 element (it was removed while HTML5 was in development). Currently it’s [part of HTML 5.1 (Working Draft)](http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-html51-20150317/semantics.html#the-details-element).

Comment: You would have to find some way of setting the `open` attribute to `true` for printing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force open the details / summary tag for Print in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646684/force-open-the-details-summary-tag-for-print-in-chrome)

Answer (score -1):

On the element, add the `open` attribute , without any value assigned. It is the best way to be sure a details element is kept open no matter what.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_details_open.asp

Comment: But this would force all attributes open on the screen, whereas I only want that to happen in print (since a user can't influence open/close states)