# srcset and printing (to paper)

Tags: css, html, printing, srcset

I have a question regarding srcset and printing images (to paper).

Let's say there are three image sizes that shall be catered depending on the screen size:

```
$image_url_1, $image_url_2, $image_url_3, $image_url_4
```

The first is the original size. The others are of 50%, 33% and 25% width.
For small screens, `$box-width-1` to `$box-width-4` are all set to 100%, so I always want to show $image_url_1.

For larger screens, `$box-width-1` to `$box-width-4` differ in size (50%, 33% and 25%), so images shall match each box size.

```
<picture>
  <source media="(max-width: 567px)" srcset="
    <?php 
      if ( $box_width == 'box-width-1' ) { echo $image_url_1; } 
      elseif ( $box_width == 'box-width-2' ) { echo $image_url_1; }
      elseif ( $box_width == 'box-width-3' ) { echo $image_url_1; }
      elseif ( $box_width == 'box-width-4' ) { echo $image_url_1; }
    ?>
  ">

  <source media="(min-width: 568px)" srcset="        
    <?php 
      if ( $box_width == 'box-width-1' ) { echo $image_url_1; } 
      elseif ( $box_width == 'box-width-2' ) { echo $image_url_2; }
      elseif ( $box_width == 'box-width-3' ) { echo $image_url_3; }
      elseif ( $box_width == 'box-width-4' ) { echo $image_url_4; }
    ?>
  ">
<img src="<?php echo $image_url_1; ?>">
</picture>
```

All of this works just fine (tested in Firefox), BUT I want print the images to paper as well, using the second srcset with varying image sizes. So far, it justs prints the single image size version.

Is there something like `<source media="print" srcset="...">`. If not – I couldn't find it – could there be an alternative way to cater different image sizes for prints as well?

Thanks!

Georg

Comment: surely it depends on your printer page size as to which image it uses?

Comment: So the page layout DIN A4 resembles max-width: 567px? Thought it would be bigger than that, but I have to check. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Just to test this quickly I set the min-/max-width to 1px, but it is still printing/pdf-ing the regular image size only.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this a bit and what you suggest seems to be the right way to achieve what you want:

```html
<picture>
  <source srcset="mdn-logo-wide.png" media="print">
  <img src="mdn-logo-narrow.png" alt="MDN">
</picture>
```

Unfortunately, no browser seems to support this. Here are the issues for [Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=758271) and [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1393118).

It looks like one of the cases for which you have to fall back on JavaScript. You can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34158303/12917821) how to hook into printing with JavaScript but I haven't tried this myself.